# Multiple y series on same chart androidplot

Tags: androidplot

i have a requirement to plot a line chart over a candlestick chart.(see first image)
 we can simply add line series over the candlestick chart. but if the data of line chart is large, it does not show the candlestick series clearly(see the second image). so is there anything to draw multiple y series on the same chart(one for the line chart and another for the candlestick chart.
[image: chart- required]

[image: chart2 current]

Comment: Diksha's answer, while short is actually (IMHO) the correct answer.  You can find a few approaches for this if you google 'androidplot normalization'.  For example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/androidplot/kYYGnOrJv5k

Answer (score 0):

you should take the maximum value and then scale all the values accordingly for candlesticks as well as line chart.:)